# How to update records with incremented values based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table `Pages`

```
+--------------------------------+
|            Pages               |
+--------------------------------+
| Name | Id | ParentId | Ordinal |
|--------------------------------|
|  A   | 1  | NULL     | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  B   | 2  | 1        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  C   | 3  | 1        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  D   | 4  | 1        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  E   | 5  | 2        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  F   | 6  | 2        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  G   | 7  | 3        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  H   | 8  | 3        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  I   | 9  | 3        | 0       |
+--------------------------------+
```

and i want to update the table with SQL, so i get

```
+--------------------------------+
|            Pages               |
+--------------------------------+
| Name | Id | ParentId | Ordinal |
|--------------------------------|
|  A   | 1  | NULL     | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  B   | 2  | 1        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  C   | 3  | 1        | 1       |
|--------------------------------|
|  D   | 4  | 1        | 2       |
|--------------------------------|
|  E   | 5  | 2        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  F   | 6  | 2        | 1       |
|--------------------------------|
|  G   | 7  | 3        | 0       |
|--------------------------------|
|  H   | 8  | 3        | 1       |
|--------------------------------|
|  I   | 9  | 3        | 2       |
+--------------------------------+
```

Column `Ordinal` must be incremental values, starting from 0.
It should start over every time column `ParentId` changes.

Comment: What is the condition

Comment: New_Ordinal -> how to find out this?

Comment: what is New_Ordinal?

Comment: See as the sequence is given by (parentid,id), why store this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. Below is the code, in case someone is interest

The `SELECT` statement

```
SET @ordinal := -1;
SET @parent := (SELECT ParentId FROM Pages WHERE ParentId IS NULL);

SELECT p.Name, p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Ordinal 
FROM (
    SELECT p.Name
        ,p.Id
        ,p.ParentId
        ,CASE WHEN @parent != p.ParentId OR @parent IS NULL
            THEN @ordinal:=0
            ELSE @ordinal:=@ordinal+1 END 
         AS Ordinal
        ,@parent:=p.parentId
    FROM Pages p
) p
ORDER BY p.ParentId, p.Ordinal;
```

The `UPDATE` statement

```
SET @ordinal := -1;
SET @parent := (SELECT ParentId FROM Pages WHERE ParentId IS NULL);

UPDATE Pages p JOIN (
    SELECT Id
        ,CASE WHEN @parent != ParentId OR @parent IS NULL
            THEN @ordinal:=0
            ELSE @ordinal:=@ordinal+1 END 
         AS Ordinal
        ,@parent:=ParentId
    FROM Pages
) p1 ON p.id = p1.id 
SET p.Ordinal = p1.Ordinal;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified answer.

Sample output :[image]
Here is the [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633634/1)

```
SELECT Name,Id,ParentId,Ordinal
FROM
(SELECT `Name`,
        `Id`,
        `ParentId`,
        (@category_num :=IF(ParentId = @ParentId,@category_num+1,0)) AS Ordinal,
        @ParentId:= `ParentId` AS Temp_swap

FROM Pages)T
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it is display rownumber

```
select *,b.row_number from page as a
join(SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,id,Parentid FROM page, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
group by Parentid
ORDER BY id)as b on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: It does not start row_number from 0 every time ParentId changes, but thanks anyway. It helps me to start.